# React wont render Hello World

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Unable to render a Hello World application on React. I've checked out other posts on SO, but can't get any of those tips to get working for me. A little help on this problem would be amazing.

```js
class Channel extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <li>Hello, World!</li>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Channel />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>React</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id='app' class='container-fluid'>
    </div>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/babel' src='app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you just getting a blank page? Did you check the network tab to see if all your files are being fetched?

Comment: I've ticked the Babel box in your Stack Snippet, and as you can see, it does now render "Hello, World!". (More about doing Stack Snippets with React [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).) It also has an error that I assume relates to one of the other scripts you're loading.

Comment: Side note: `li` elements cannot be direct children of `div`s, just `ul` and `ol` elements (well, and `template`s).

Comment: @LakshyaThakur Yep, just a blank page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was with the last script import.

Downgrading Babel-core to 5.8 worked for me. There seems to be an issue with version 6.